# alternative of JSoup or how to clean whitespaces

Tags: java, html, jsoup

Does somebody know an alternative of **JSoup**?

Or how to clean sequences like `<p>&nbsp;</p>`?

**HTML Clean plug-in for jQuery** works well for me, but I'm interested in doing the html code cleaning at **server side**, not in the **client side**.

Or, what is the replaceAll expression to do??:

```
String cleanS = dirtyS.replaceAll("<p>&nbsp;</p>", ""); //This doesnt work
```

I have discovered that the dirty html comes with mixed sequences of blank spaces **#160**, and others like **#32**.

So, what I need is a expression to remove whatever mixture of them.

[image: mix space blank]

Comment: What do you want as a result ? the whole paragraph removed ? or <p></p> ?

Comment: I want to clean the whole paragraph

Comment: If you upload the file where we can get it, it would be easier to inspect it and give a working code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can change the `OutputSettings` for this:

**Example:**

```
final String html = ...;


OutputSettings settings = new OutputSettings();
settings.escapeMode(Entities.EscapeMode.xhtml);

String cleanHtml = Jsoup.clean(html, "", Whitelist.relaxed(), settings);
```

This is possible with a `Document` parsed by Jsoup too:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(...);
doc.outputSettings().escapeMode(Entities.EscapeMode.xhtml);

// ...
```

---

**Edit:**

Removing tags:

```
doc.select("p:matchesOwn((?is) )").remove();
```

Please note: after `(?is)` there's **not** a blank, but *char #160* (= nbsp).
This will remove all p-Tags whose own text is only a `&nbsp;`. If you want do so with all other tags, you can replace the `p:` with `*:`.

Comment: <p>&nbsp;</p> returns <p> </p>; but i want to remove the whole line <p>&nbsp;</p>

Comment: Ok, see my edit. But please make shure you dont write a blank instead of char 160 in the regex :-)

Comment: As you say, with `code`doc.select("p:matchesOwn((?is)\u00a0").remove();`code` I remove `code`<p>&nbsp;</p>`code`, but how can I remove `code`<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;...etc...</p>`code`
???

Comment: If the code from above doesn't remove more than one `&nbsp;` you can use this regex instead: `"p:matchesOwn((?is) +?)"`.

Comment: Thanks for the efforts, but none of this work: "p:matchesOwn((?is)\u00a0+?)" "p:matchesOwn((?is)(\u00a0)+?)"

Comment: Did you copy & paste the regex of my post? Please try it with the "blank" as in my post and not with \u00a0.

Comment: Ollo, I have discovered that the dirty html comes with a mixture of #160 and #32 whitespaces. Do you know the master expression to kill all of them? thanks thanks thanks...

Comment: Please try this one `"p:matchesOwn((?is) ), p:not(:matchesOwn((?is)\\S+?)"`. Unfortunately a simple `p:matchesOwn((?is)[  ]+?")` didn't work (there are #160 and #32 between []). Even `p:matchesOwn((?is)[ \\s]+?")` didn't (using Jsoup 1.7.1) ... maybe a bug? However ... now there's a combination between a regex for #160 and one for whitespaces, let us see if it works :-)

Comment: Hi Ollo, with your "p:matchesOwn((?is) ), p:not(:matchesOwn((?is)\\S+?)" expression, all inside <p>...</p> its removed, except one blank (<p> </p>). Don't worry. I think I'am going to use HTML Clean plug-in for jQuery (and give you the green stick for the time spent on this issue)

Comment: Doh! As stated above, Jsoup doesn't support the posted regex otherwise it won't be a problem. Maybe [HtmlCleaner](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/) is an option too. But if the jquery Plugin does it's job ... perfect! :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you have the document object, you can loop over the paragrap elements and remove all those that don't have text (or non white space text) in them. before checking if the text is empty, you can replace the occurrences of NBSP; with white space. Assuming your working ith UTF-8 documents the following might work for you:

```
public static final String NBSP_IN_UTF8 = "\u00a0";
```

Assuming you know how to get the Document object, the loop to clean is simple: select the paragraph elements and remove empty ones:

```
org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc= ...   //obtain your document object  
for (org.jsoup.nodes.Element element : doc.select("p")) {
    if ( !element.hasText() || element.text().replaceAll(NBSP_IN_UTF8, "").trim().equals("") ) {
       element.remove();
    }
  }
```